# Swift - Callback call after click

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I using callback to develop BLEModule.
Below is a simple code for checking the power.
It works well in ViewDidLoad.
but, why doesn't the code respond in @IBAction?

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ble = BLEManager.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ble.confirmPower { (result) in
            print(result) //true or false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func checkBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        print("power")
        ble.confirmPower { (result) in
            print(result) //non-response
        }
    }
}
```

I am using callback to develop BLEModule.
Below is a simple code for checking the power.
It works well in ViewDidLoad.
but, why doesn't the code respond in @IBAction?

Comment: Have you verified that "power" prints to the console when the button is clicked? If not you probably forgot to connect the button in your Storyboard to the `checkBtn(_:)` method in you `ViewController` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback will be called when `centralManagerDidUpdateState` is fired, I believe `centralManagerDidUpdateState` will be fired on app start, so the callback in your `viewDidLoad` will be called. However, when you pressed the button, `centralManagerDidUpdateState` is not fired so the callback is not called.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. my code is like this code.

Comment: result was still the same.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I just tried, but it didn't run.
And these errors output :
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: thx! :) I knew I made a mistake in init code line. I've got to hand to you

Answer (score 0):

You should check in your storyboard that your scanningBtn is linked to the proper touchEvent such as `touchUpInside` you can do this by right clicking on your button. A little more info to help resolve your issue would be appreciated.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i already linked is checked. print code line is executed and callback code line does not run.